# Swiftで16進数をShift-JIS表示へとするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか

Tags: swift, ios

題名の通り、Swiftで文字列をShift-JIS表示へと変更する事は可能でしょうか。

```
let str = “あいうえお“

for scalar in str.unicodeScalars {
     let aStr = String(scaler.value, radix:16) // 3042 3044 3046 3948 304Aとなる
...
}
```

Unicode スカラ表現を16進数とすると、3042 3044 3046 3948 304A が出ます。その数値を最終的な結果としてShift-JIS表示となる B0D0F0H0J0  へと変換したいと考えています。どの様な方法がありますでしょうか。

Comment: 「Unicodeの16進数(3042 3044 3046 3948 304A)としました」と言うのが何をやったのかよくわかりません。できれば、コードを交えて何をやったのかよくわかるようにしてください。ただし、Swiftの文字列をShift-JIS表現に変換するのに、何らかの中間的ステップを必要とすることはありません。`String`型から直接変換できます。また「Shift-JIS表示へと変更」と言うのもよくわからないです。欲しいのは「Shift-JISのバイナリーデータ」でしょうか? それとも「そのバイナリーデータを16死んで文字列に変換したもの」でしょうか?

Comment: 3042 3044 3046 3948 304A ではなく、3042 3044 3046 3048 304A と、3948→3048 ではないでしょうか？　その上で期待される文字列は、`0B0D0F0H0J`ではありませんか？

Comment: 質問が[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701)の様な気がします。本当にやりたいことは何か？の説明が欠けていて、そのための手段として考えた今回の質問と、行ったことを省略して、必要だと考えている`B0D0F0H0J0`をどう導き出した（そして、どう使うのか？）の説明もないため、@x001017さんの本当に行いたいことが解らず、適切な回答がつきづらい状態に陥ってしまっているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 回答にいただいたコメントをもとに回答を修正しました。なかなか正解に至れないのは、質問者さんのせいばかりのような言い方をしてしまっていますが、私自身`B0D0F0H0J0`が「16進数っぽく見える架空のデータ」なんて思い込んでしまっていたことも大きな原因の一つなので、反省しています。ただ、多くの読者にとってご質問の意図はわかりにくいものになっているのだと思うので、元ネタのリンク先は是非追加しておいてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントによると、ご質問内容は誤った変換を繰り返した結果「あいうえお」が「B0D0F0H0J0」となってしまうという挙動をSwiftで再現したいと言うことのようです。

「B0D0F0H0J0」と言う結果は「Shift-JIS表示」でも何でもなく、間違ったエンコーディングでデータを読み取って文字化けした結果、です。

Swiftで再現するコードは以下のような感じになります。
(別のエンコーディングを試しやすいようにコードを修正しました。)

```
let str = "あいうえお"
let encodedBytes = str.data(using: .utf16LittleEndian) ?? Data()
let forcedReinterpretedStr = String(data: encodedBytes, encoding: .shiftJIS) ?? "**not a valid string**"
print(forcedReinterpretedStr)
```

`str`の中身を色々変えて試してみるとわかりますが、文字列のUTF-16表現というのはシフトJISとして解釈できるバイト列になるとは限らないため、`**not a valid string**`の方が表示されるかもしれません。

(質問の書き方というのも難しいかもしれませんが、元ネタがリンクで示せるなら、そのリンクを含めていただいていれば、もっと早く上記のコードをお示しできたと思います。)

---

**修正**
以下の記述は質問者さんの意図が掴みきれないときに書いたものですが、Swiftの`String`型の挙動を理解するために有用と思われるため、そのまま残しておきます。

コメントに書いたように「Shift-JIS表示へと変更」と言うのがよくわからないのですが、Swiftの文字列では文字列側に「Shift_JIS」といったエンコーディング情報は保存されませんし、Swiftの内部では常にシステム側で決められた内部表現(現在はUTF-8)で文字列を表現しています。

したがって、出来ることは「文字列」から「その文字列をシフトJISで表現した時のバイト列(バイナリーデータ)を得ること」になります。

```
import Foundation

let str = "あいうえお"

let sjisData = str.data(using: .shiftJIS)!
print(type(of: sjisData)) //-> Data
print(sjisData as NSData) //-> {length = 10, bytes = 0x82a082a282a482a682a8}
```

日本の技術者が「シフトJIS」と言った場合、Windowsの拡張文字も含めた文字セット(IANAの`"Windows-31J"`)を表すことが多いのですが、Swiftの`String.Encoding.shiftJIS`という定数はそちらを表すようです。IANA規定の`"Shift_JIS"`を表したいのであれば、少々面倒なことをしないといけないのですが、実用的には必要になることは滅多にないでしょう。

以上のコードで`sjisData`は「シフトJIS表現のバイト列」を保持する`Data`型の値になります。

---

この変換結果を使いたいときには、さらにその用途によって`Data`から変換することが必要になるかもしれません。

例えば「シフトJISの16進表現を表す文字列」(デバッグ用途を除けば、こんなものが必要になることは滅多にありませんが)が欲しいのであれば、こんな感じになります。

```
let sjisHex = sjisData.map {String(format: "%02X", $0)}
                .joined()
print(type(of: sjisHex)) //-> String
print(sjisHex) //-> 82A082A282A482A682A8
```

---

「結果をファイルに保存したい」と言うコメントをいただいたので、そのためのコード例を示しておきます。上の`sjisHex`の部分は無視して、変換結果の`Data`をファイルに書き込めば良いだけなので、いくらでも方法はありますが、以下は例の１つとして。

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file")
do {
    try sjisData.write(to: url)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

再度のコメントで「outputとして string型の B0D0F0H0J0 という結果を得たい」とありますが、その例は上の`sjisHex`の部分を見てください。「ファイルに保存」するにしても、「文字列を得たい」にしても、「そのファイルを後でどう使うのか」「その文字列を後でどう使うのか」までわかれば、「もっと簡単にこう書ける」と言う場合があります。

まだしっくりこなければ、そこら辺の情報をいただければ何かお手伝いできるかもしれません。

---

まだ、話が噛み合わないような気がするので、少し一般的になってしまいますが、Swiftの文字列について説明しておきます。

Swiftでは、`String`型において、文字列をUnicode準拠の方法で格納すると規定されており、また、Unicodeベースのいくつかのデータ表現については簡単に変換できるようになっています。

```
let str = "あいうえお"
//Unicodeスカラー
print(str.unicodeScalars.map{String(format: "U+%04X", $0.value)}.joined(separator: " "))
//->U+3042 U+3044 U+3046 U+3048 U+304A U+1F600

//UTF-16コード単位
print(str.utf16.map{String(format: "0x%04X", $0)}.joined(separator: " "))
//->0x3042 0x3044 0x3046 0x3048 0x304A 0xD83D 0xDE00

//UTF-8コード単位
print(str.utf8.map{String(format: "0x%02X", $0)}.joined(separator: " "))
//->0xE3 0x81 0x82 0xE3 0x81 0x84 0xE3 0x81 0x86 0xE3 0x81 0x88 0xE3 0x81 0x8A 0xF0 0x9F 0x98 0x80
```

このうち、現在のSwiftでは3つめのUTF-8コード単位でデータが格納されており、**これをシフトJISに変換することはできません**。

また、古いSwiftやObjective-C(の`NSString`)では、2つ目のUTF-16コード単位でデータが格納されています。**これをシフトJISに変換することはできません**。

Unicodeスカラーにしろ、UTF-16にしろUTF-8にしろUnicode規格で規定されたデータ表現であり、シフトJISと言うのはUnicodeではありませんから、何をどうやっても**上記のメソッド(と言うかプロパティですが、`unicodeScalars`, `utf16`, `utf8`)からシフトJISのバイト列が得られることは絶対にありません**。

---

Swiftの他、Objective-C, C#, Java, JavaScriptなんかも、同じように文字列の内部表現は固定であり、その「内部表現をシフトJISに変換すること」は決してできません。

これに対して、例えばPHPの「文字列」と言うのは単なるバイト列であり、

`"他の文字列あいうえお他の文字列"`と言った文字列があるときに`"他の文字列" + ("あいうえお"をシフトJIS変換したもの) + "他の文字列"`といった「文字列」を作ることも可能です。

PHPで上記のような処理をしている部分をSwiftでどのように行えば良いのかは、実際に出来上がった「文字列」をどう使っているのかを見ないと、何とも言えません。

結果の「文字列」をどう使いたいのか、具体的にお示しください。

Comment: 分かりにくくすいません。質問内容を変更しました。Unicode スカラ表現を16進数とすると、3042 3044 3046 3948 304A が出ます。その数値を最終的な結果としてShift-JIS表示となる B0D0F0H0J0 へと変換したいと考えています。B0D0F0H0J0という結果をファイルに保存したいと考えています。

Comment: @x001017 さん、ご質問の編集ありがとうございました。これで「Unicodeの16進数」と書かれていた部分はよく分かったのですが、まだ「どんなinputから」「どんなoutputを得たいのか」がよくわかりません。(「そう言うことを明らかにして欲しい」と言うのが明らかにはなっていなかったかもしれませんね。)「inputは`String`型の値」だろうと思うのですが、回答本文に書いたように、Swiftでは文字列の内部表現をShift_JISにする、と言うことはできません。「結果をファイルに保存したい」のであれば、`String`ではなく、変換後の`Data`をファイルに保存することになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。inputはString型の値です。ファイルに保存したいも不要でした。すいません。outputとして string型の B0D0F0H0J0 という結果を得たいと考えています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。例のsjisHexの部分ですが、82A082A282A482A682A8 = B0D0F0H0J0  であるという事ではあると思うのですが、文字列としてB0D0F0H0J0を得て、他のStringの文字列と結合し、“他の文字列B0D0F0H0J0他の文字列“にしprintで表示できればゴールという形となります。色々と分かりにくく申し訳ありません。

Comment: @x001017 さん、上のように`sjisHex`を作成して、`“他の文字列\(sjisHex)他の文字列“`とやれば良いだけのように思います。それでは何かダメなのでしょうか?

Comment: 上記ですと、“他の文字列82A082A282A482A682A8他の文字列“となるとおもわれますが、最終結果が、“他の文字列B0D0F0H0J0他の文字列“と表示されて欲しいと考えています

Comment: @x001017 さん、「あいうえお」をシフトJISで表現したものを16進表記すると82A082A282A482A682A8となります。ご自身でも「82A082A282A482A682A8 = B0D0F0H0J0 である」書いていただいていますが、その前提で`“他の文字列82A082A282A482A682A8他の文字列“`と`“他の文字列B0D0F0H0J0他の文字列“`とでは何がどう違うのでしょうか? まず「あいうえお」のシフトJIS16進表現は`82A082A282A482A682A8`です。`B0D0F0H0J0`と言う16進表現でさえないものが混ざると話が混乱してしまうように思います。『「あいうえお」のシフトJIS16進表現は`82A082A282A482A682A8`』が入った文字列にどんな処理をしたらどんな結果が得られることを期待しているのでしょうか?

Comment: OOPerさん、「あいうえお」をシフトJIS16進数で表すと82A082A282A482A682A8 だとおもいますが、そうではなく、「あいうえお」のUnicode スカラ表現を16進数で表した「3042 3044 3046 3948 304A」をシフトJIS表示したB0D0F0H0J0という文字列を取得できないのかというところで質問した次第です。

Comment: @x001017 さん、まず`B0D0F0H0J0`なんて架空のデータは混乱を長引かせるので使わないようにしてください。追記しましたが『あいうえお」のUnicode スカラ表現を16進数で表した= 82A082A282A482A682A8 』にすることは決してできません。シフトJISはUnicodeではないし、シフトJISの各バイトは「Unicodeスカラ」ではありませんから。

Comment: 下記の別のページではありますが、エクセルの表示の様に、https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9279655.html

Comment: @x001017 さん、「架空」ではなく、『誤った変換を繰り返した結果、「あいうえお」が「B0D0F0H0J0」になってしまった』のをSwiftで再現したいと言うことだったのでしょうか、そのような情報は是非ともご質問本文に含めておいてください。

Comment: 誤った変換を繰り返した訳ではなく、Unicodeの１６進数だと「3042 3044 3046 3048 304A」
メモリ上では「42304430463048304A30」
これをシフトＪＩＳだと「B0D0F0H0J0」となると記述してあるため、それをSwiftで再現したいと考えています

Comment: @x001017 さん、UnicodeのUTF-16表現のバイト列はシフトJISとは全く関係ありませんので、それを無理にシフトJISとして解釈しようとするのは「誤った変換」。UTF-16で保存されたファイルをシフトJISとして読み込もうとしているようなものです。当然文字化けしますが、あなたのご質問は「そのような誤った指定による文字化けを再現したい」と言うことになります。

Comment: 色々とすみません。その誤った指定を再現出来ましたらと思います。

Comment: OOPerさん 大変ありがとうございます。非常に参考になりました。元が元だけであった為に大変申し訳ありませんでした。後ほど、質問の方にもサイトの方含めまして変更させていただきます。貴重なお時間を頂きありがとうございます。